# Python Reduce conditional expression

Tags: python, conditional-statements

I have 9 variables a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i and I loop them inside 9 for loop from 0 to 9. But the range may vary.

I want all sequences of them abcdefghi, such that there is no repeated number.

Right now I have this, below:

```
for a in range(0, 9): 
    for b in range(0,9): #it doesn't have to start from 0
    ....
        for i in range(0, 9):
             if a != b and a != c ... a != i
                b != c and b != d ... b != i
                c != d and c != e ... c != i
                ... h != i:

                print (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
```

There are 9! = 362880 of them,

But how can I reduce the conditional expression? And what if the ranges for the for loops are different?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have a look at the itertools module, I think the [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) function is what you are looking for

Comment: What are you trying to test? In words. There is almost certainly an easy was to do this.

Comment: @malik you're right.

Comment: i'm trying to solve the sudoku problem, need to check that all rows have different value, and i need their index value to be different. Each of them also have different domain range, not all of them have a domain from 0 to 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this with the `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import permutations

for arrangement in permutations('abcdefghi', 9):
    print ''.join(arrangement)
```

Comment: i was actually looking for a way to reduce the conditional expression, but i think this way works too. Thanks

Comment: Do you want me to add a for loop version?

Comment: no, but what if the domain for the variables are not all 0 to 9. What do I can in that case?

Comment: The second argument indicates the length of the permutations. We used 9 because that is the length of the range of letters.

Comment: yes, but the permutation only work when i have 9 for loops looping from 0 to 9, but what if the ranges are different for some of the for loop? How  can i check for not repeated number, i think i need the conditional expression.

Comment: The `itertools` permutation takes care of this for you. Why are you fixated on the loop?

Comment: what if i want sequence of abcdefghi such taht a,b,c,e,g is value from 0 to 9, and d,f,h,i in the range of 1 to 5.

Comment: @OuYe: this answer doesn't solve your problem! It returns permutations of **characters**, not numbers: ie, a="c", b = "f", c="b", d="i".

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import permutations

for perm in permutations(range(1, 10), 9):
    print(" ".join(str(i) for i in perm))
```

which gives

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 7 9
1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9 7
1 2 3 4 5 6 9 7 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 9 8 7

# ... etc - 9! = 362880 permutations
```

---

> what if i want sequence of abcdefghi such taht a,b,c,e,g is value from 0 to 9, and d,f,h,i in the range of 1 to 5

This is a bit more complicated, but still achievable. It is easier to pick the values in `d..i` first:

```
from itertools import permutations

for d,f,h,i,unused in permutations([1,2,3,4,5], 5):
    for a,b,c,e,g in permutations([unused,6,7,8,9], 5):
        print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i)
```

which gives

```
5 6 7 1 8 2 9 3 4
5 6 7 1 9 2 8 3 4
5 6 8 1 7 2 9 3 4
5 6 8 1 9 2 7 3 4
5 6 9 1 7 2 8 3 4
5 6 9 1 8 2 7 3 4
5 7 6 1 8 2 9 3 4
5 7 6 1 9 2 8 3 4
5 7 8 1 6 2 9 3 4
5 7 8 1 9 2 6 3 4

# ... etc - 5! * 5! = 14400 permutations
```

---

For the general case (ie Sudoku) you need a more general solution - a constraint solver like [python-constraint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-constraint/1.2) (for intro see [the python-constraint home page](http://labix.org/python-constraint)).

Then your solution starts to look like

```
from constraint import Problem, AllDifferentConstraint

p = Problem()
p.addVariables("abceg", list(range(1,10)))
p.addVariables("dfhi",  list(range(1, 6)))
p.addConstraint(AllDifferentConstraint())

for sol in p.getSolutionIter():
    print("{a} {b} {c} {d} {e} {f} {g} {h} {i}".format(**sol))
```

which gives

```
9 8 7 4 6 3 5 2 1
9 8 7 4 5 3 6 2 1
9 8 6 4 7 3 5 2 1
9 8 6 4 5 3 7 2 1
9 8 5 4 6 3 7 2 1
9 8 5 4 7 3 6 2 1
9 7 8 4 5 3 6 2 1
9 7 8 4 6 3 5 2 1
9 7 6 4 8 3 5 2 1
9 7 6 4 5 3 8 2 1
9 7 5 4 6 3 8 2 1

# ... etc - 14400 solutions
```

Comment: Except it's a permutation of letters a through i. And I usually try to avoid the variable combo as it contradicts the whole permutation thing.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: "I want all sequences of them abcdefghi, such that there is no repeated **number**" - I took that to mean he wanted digits.